# LINQ to Entities - Multiple Joins - Null Reference Exception on 'Select'

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to convert a SQL query to a LINQ to entities query, but am having some problems with the LINQ **select** block.

Here is the SQL query which performs as expected:

```
SELECT distinct( p.PendingID,
        p.Description,
        p.Date,
        f.Status,
        u.UserName,
        m.MapID
    FROM    Pending p
    JOIN    Users u 
   ON p.UserID = u.UserID
    LEFT JOIN Forks f 
   ON p.PendingID = f.PendingID
    LEFT JOIN Maps m
      ON f.ForkID = m.ForkID
    ORDER BY p.Date DESC
```

Here is the LINQ to entities query as I have it thus far:

```
var pList = (from pending in pendingItems
// JOIN
from user in userList.Where(u => pending.UserID == u.UserID)
// LEFT OUTER JOIN
from fork in forkList.Where(f => pending.ID == f.PendingID)
.DefaultIfEmpty()
// LEFT OUTER JOIN
from map in mapList.Where(m => fork.ID == m.ForkID)
.DefaultIfEmpty()
orderby pending.Date descending
select new
{
 ItemID = pending.ID,                 // Guid
 Description = pending.Description,   // String
 Date = pending.Date,                 // DateTime
 Status = fork.Status,               // Int32 (*ERROR HERE*)
 UserName = user.UserName,            // String 
 MapID = map.ID                       // Guid (*ERROR HERE*)
})
.Distinct()
.ToList();
```

The LINQ query fails on either of the following 2 lines, which attempt to assign values retrieved from **left outer join** results. If the following lines are omitted, the LINQ query completes without errors:

```
Status = fork.Status,
MapID = map.ID
```

Why are those 2 property assignments failing within the LINQ query's select block?

Comment: Are you actually running this against EF or an in-memory facsimile of your database? Secondly, is this code in LINQPad and can you check the generated SQL (if against EF)?

Comment: I think this is a compiler error which is why he can see errors on both lines.

Comment: tster: The title of the post says "Null Reference Exception" so I doubt it's a compiler error.

Comment: @Anthony: I am running against in-memory collections after they have previously been retrieved from EF context.

Comment: @tster: No compiler errors; runtime issues only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that due to your outer joins, `fork` and `map` may be null. Of course when they're null, you can't access their properties. You may need something like this:

```
Status = (fork == null) ? null : fork.Status,
MapID = (map == null) ? null : map.ID
```

Comment: They can't be null because DefaultIfEmpty returns a collection and if there are none, it returns a singleton collection.  However, the value in the collection can be null.

Comment: tster: The `map` and `fork` variables iterate over the values returned by `DefaultIfEmpty` so they can indeed be null.

Comment: Oh shoot, I am used to looking at `let x = ...` instead of multiple from clauses.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Worked like a charm. I had forgotten about the possibility that the entire object could be null in each case, where the outer joins were applied.